# jquery-textcomplete how to disable

Tags: jquery

I've had a look thru the docs, and I can't find out how to programatically disable textcomplete after it has been initialized to my text input box.
I need something like this, but perhaps I'm forced? to change the `Match` to something impossible, sounds messy:

```
$('#outgoing_text').textcomplete([{option:'disable'}]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are talking about text box autocomplete right? Then try it like following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following code:

```
$('#outgoing_text').textcomplete('destroy');
```

It's written here:

https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete/blob/master/doc/how_to_use.md

Comment: eh it seams im blind :(

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#myForm').on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
    $(this).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
});
```

Comment: Please provide a explanation with your solution.